# Fetching data from Oracle using JSP

Tags: jsp

I want to fetch data from Oracle using JSP. Multiple parameters should be passed from the form textbox.

```
<form method="post" action="num_post.jsp">
Enter Number: <input name="num" type="text" id="num" />

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here in the text field I want to pass multiple parameters, e.g. 123,456,789,896, etc.

Now in the num_post.jsp I have this code to request the passed parameter in JSP.

```
<%
 String[] num=request.getParameterValues("num");

 int i=0;

 for(i=0;i<num.length;i++)
 {
      out.println("number Elements       :"+num[i]+"<br/>");
 }
%>
```

Now I want to fetch data from Oracle using the array parameters, for example: `num[i]`

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import = "java.io.*"%>
<%
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");
 Statement st=con.createStatement();
 String sql = "SELECT * from jha where num IN '"+num[i]+"'" ;
 ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
 %>
```

This throws an `ArrayOutOfBound` exception.

Comment: try my solution and let know. If you got the solution, then accept it otherwise elaborate your problem.

Comment: where are you ?? at least let me know, whether your resolve or not ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`String[] num=(request.getParameter("num").toString()).split(",");`

instead of

`String[] num=request.getParameterValues("num");`

**=====UPDATE=====**

As you specified, **ArrayIndexOutOfBound**, which means, you are trying to access out of index from your array. And, it is clear

```
String[] num=(request.getParameter("num").toString()).split(","); // let say array size would be 4
int i=0;  // i initialized by 0

 for(i=0;i<num.length;i++)
 {
      out.println("number Elements       :"+num[i]+"<br/>"); 
 }
  // when control reached here, the value of i will be 4 (which is out of index)
```

Now, in your query you are trying to access `4` index element, which is not there.

```
"SELECT * from jha where num IN '"+num[i]+"'"   // here value  of i is 4
```

That's why you are getting **ArrayIndexOutOfBound**. Got it ???

One more thing, the query, which you have written there, is applicable to check only one value from your array. So, you need to change your query. It won't show you, your expected output.

Comment: I'm not Tim Medora, also please elaborate what does not work.

Comment: correction var______ the sql query not accepting the parameters// i am able to retrieve the parameters from textbox but sql does not pass that parameters to further fetch the details from database .     String sql = "SELECT * from jha where num IN '"+num[i]+"'" ;

Comment: @ShaanSonu if my solution is helpful, then accept it and close this thread.